# Retain the drop down selected value after page submit (page reload) in spring jsp page

Tags: javascript, html, spring, jsp

I've a Spring jsp page where I've multiple drop downs. User can select the value from the drop down and click on submit to get to see only the results of the selected value. For this I've to retain the user selected value after submit. I tried storing the selected index in javasript but after page load it sets to default value.

```
<form:form id="fee" method="post" modelAttribute="clientForm" commandName = "clientForm" 
action="<%= request.getContextPath().toString()%>/addFee.do">

<form:select path="client" class="myForm" style="width:235px">
<form:option value="0">All </form:option>
    <form:options items="${clientsList}">
</form:options>
```

And my javascript function :

```
function fnGo(action,elementId)
{   
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('myForm');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
{
    if(elements[i].selectedIndex == 0)
        elements[i].selectedIndex = 0;
}

document.getElementById(elementId).action = action;
document.getElementById(elementId).method = "POST";
document.getElementById(elementId).submit();
}
```

My controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addFee.do",method = RequestMethod.POST, params={"submit"})
protected @ResponseBody ModelAndView   submitFeeValues(@ModelAttribute("clientForm") MyForm myForm ) 
throws Exception {

model = new ModelAndView("fee");
model.addObject("clientForm",myForm);
model.addObject("clientsList",myForm.getClientList());

return model;
}
```

Are there any better ways of storing the index and passing on to the page after the page gets reloaded?

Comment: Can you provide the complete form and your controller code?

Comment: I've edited the question. Do I've to pass anything from controller for the selected index?

Comment: where do you declare client the path value for your select? your form select shoud be selected based on this value? do you have a modelAttribute in your Form?

Comment: Yes I've a modelAttribute in the form. And through this attribute I'm accessing in my controller. The path variable is declared in the form bean.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a working example you should do like this,
on your jsp you can do like this:

```
    <form:form modelAttribute="clientForm"  method="post">
                <form:select path="client" class="myForm" style="width:235px">
<form:option value="0">All</form:option>
    <form:options items="${clientsList}">
</form:options>

         </form:form>
```

Your ClientForm Like this

```
public class ClientForm {


    private String              client;

    public String getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public void setClient(String client) {
        this.client = client;
    }
}
```

In your controller do something like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/client")
@SessionAttributes(value = "clientForm")
public class TraductionController {
     @ModelAttribute("clientForm")
        public ClientForm getClientForm() {
            return new ClientForm();
        }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/list" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String search(ModelMap model, ClientForm clientForm) throws ServiceTechException {
        //get clientLists
        model.addAttribute("clientsList", clientsList);
        model.addAttribute("clientForm", clientForm);
        return "client/list";
    }

}
```

Comment: yeah I've added the similar way. I've no problem retrieving the value in my controller. The question is to retain the selected value and keep that as selected in the drop down.how can I do that?

Comment: add your controller code, your ModelAttribute class, and your complete form on jsp.